# Do D&D dragon scales have any lore?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons

Is there any lore within D&D relating to the nature/structure of dragon scales?

Particularly I am interested in how their scales are distinct from the scales of various types of reptiles in terms of materials and physical structure

Comment: The Role Playing Games SE might be a better place?

Comment: They're magical.

Comment: @DavidW Is there anything more than that?

Comment: I guess they aren't very different from from, say, pangolins, but magic makes them tougher and resistant to one of D&D's "elements", much like it does with metal armor, I guess.

Comment: related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/113849/do-dragons-and-dragonborn-naturally-shed-or-molt-scales

Answer (score 2):

The Draconomicon (3e) gives a few details on how dragon scales compare to other animals:

> A dragon’s skin resembles crocodile hide—tough, leathery. and thick. Unlike a crocodile, however, a dragon has hundreds of hard, durable scales covering its body. A dragon’s scales are keratinous, like its spines. Unlike the spines, however, a dragon’s scales are not attached to its skeleton, and the dragon cannot make them move. The scales are much harder and less flexible than the spines, with a resistance to blows that exceeds that of steel.
> ...
> A dragon’s scales grow throughout its lifetime, albeit very slowly. Unlike most other scaled creatures, a dragon neither sheds its skin nor sheds individual scales. Instead, its individual scales grow larger, and it also grows new scales as its body gets bigger. Over the years, a scale may weather and crack near the edges, but its slow growth usually proves sufficient to replace any portion that breaks off. Dragons occasionally lose scales, especially if they become badly damaged.

Dragon scales are used in the making of countless types of equipment, in addition to being material components of some spells.